# Powershell - Getting a persons age

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a person age in Years,Months,Days,Hours,Minutes and Seconds.

This is what I got so far (you can tell I'm a total powershell beginner):

```
$now = [datetime]::now
[datetime]$birthday = "12/22/2012 03:22:00"
$age = [datetime]$now - $birthday

Write-Host "My daughter's age is:" $age.Days "days" ($age.Hours) "hours" ($age.Minutes) "minutes" ($age.Milliseconds) "seconds"
```

The output is:

```
My daughter's age is: 59 days 10 hours 27 minutes 76 seconds
```

It's ok, but it would be more awesome have the output more 'human readable':

```
1 Month 19 Days 10 hours 28 minutes 16 seconds
```

This is actually way more difficult than I initially expected. The code must know how many days has each month in order to split days into months and days. And also consider that this year is leap year!

Maybe PowerShell can help here with some of its magic!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after.

```
[datetime]$birthday = "12/22/2012 03:22:00"
$span = [datetime]::Now - $birthday
$age = New-Object DateTime -ArgumentList $Span.Ticks

Write-Host "My daughter's age is:" $($age.Year -1) Years $($age.Month -1) Months $age.Day "days" ($age.Hour) "hours" ($age.Minute) "minutes" ($age.second) "seconds"
```

Comment: Looks better, but the output of your code for the date "12/22/2012 03:27:00" is "My daughter's age is: 3 Months 1 days 11 hours 8 minutes 21 seconds" and I'm quite sure my daughter is less than 2 Months :-)

Comment: I'll have a look, I think that's cause as a result of [datetime]::MinValue

Comment: Thank you! It works. I've tested using the date 01/01/2013 and the result is '0 Years 1 Months 19 days 15 hours 44 minutes 6 seconds' Which is correct. But it's quite shocking to find out that my daughters age, who was born 12/22/2012, is actually '2 Months 1 days 15 hours 40 minutes 23 seconds' I though she'd be 2 months within 2 days, the 22nd! According to the code, 59 days = 2 months and 1 day. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Check it with the day after your birthday. There is 1 day to much!

Correct are:

```
[datetime]$birthday = "12/22/2012 03:22:00"
$span = [datetime]::Now - $birthday
$age = New-Object DateTime -ArgumentList $Span.Ticks

Write-Host "My daughter's age is:" $($age.Year-1) Years $($age.Month-1) Months ($age.Day-1) "days" ($age.Hour) "hours" ($age.Minute) "minutes" ($age.second) "seconds"
```